Nginx or uWSGI to serve sitemap and robots?
Does it matter whether it's nginx or uwsgi that serves sitemap.xml and robots.txt? If it's uwsgi, then I'd need to add the two routes in my python server, which I feel like gets a bit cluttered. With nginx, I can just copy the server configuration file if I want to start another project.
Does it matter from an SEO or best practice stand point?

It doesn't. It's impossible from outside to find out which way it's done. So, from the SEO standpoint, you can do either way.
Typically you're having Nginx at the front end, so Nginx will cache the static output from uWSGI if that's done properly, so it'll be the Nginx which would be serving anyway.
These files are generated and stored, and then they are no different than other static files on the server.
For the last two reasons, It's sensible to make Nginx to do it, as with all the rest static files you are serving.
